# How do I replace Pandas missing values using a function applied on each row?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

Given the following source data:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import re

data = [
("1 Bedroom 1 Bathroom Apartment", 1, 1),
("We've got a great 2br2ba over here!", np.nan, np.nan),
("Luxurious Apartment. Bedrooms: 3 Bathrooms: 3", np.nan, np.nan)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['description', 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms'])
```

I want to scrape the `description` field for the bedrooms and bathrooms. I have a regular expression  and a function that will do this:

```
def quantity_in_string(search_text, pattern):
    '''receives a string and a pattern, returns the highest quantity for the pattern described in the string'''
    unusable_matches = ['.', '..','...', '']
    matches = re.findall(pattern, search_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
    if type(matches) is list: 
        if matches == []: return np.nan
        matches = [j for i in matches for j in i if i not in unusable_matches]
        return max(matches)

bedroom_expression = r"(?:bedrooms:[ ]*(\d+\.*\d*))|(?:(\d+\.*\d*)[ ]*(?:bed|br|bd|bedroom))"
```

My question is, how do I apply `quantity_in_string` to `df` and replace missing values with the output from this function?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what was your result? For `apply`ing a function to a dataframe or series, you can use the built-in method [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Comment: The distinction with my question, however, is that apply will overwrite all values, rather than those just missing, unless I handle populated values in the function. However, things like `isnan(row.bedrooms)` or `row.bedrooms == np.nan` aren't behaving how I expect

Answer (score 0):

You can use **apply** and then the **isna** function that returns index where the value is na and modify only these values

```
bedroom_guess = df['description'].apply(lambda x: quantity_in_string(x, bedroom_expression))
df.loc[df['bedrooms'].isna(),['bedrooms']] = bedroom_guess[df['bedrooms'].isna()]
```